# FLV Disappeared from Site

Tags: flash, video, flv

I have a website that had a flv file embedded on the home page. All of a sudden the flv does not appear on the page. It shows in the source file, and appears in the dreamweaver page that I use, but does not appear on the site anymore. I have the most current flash player so that does not seem to be the issue. I have tried it on both pc and mac and the video no longer loads.

http://www.leadershiprockland.org/

The file shows that it is on the server and in the proper location. Here are screenshots from the web page and from Dreamweaver.

[image: Web page showing missing video space]

[image: dreamweaver page with video in place]

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="342" height="291" id="FLVPlayer">
    <param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
    <param name="salign" value="lt" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Halo_Skin_3&streamName=LeadershipRocklandFinal&autoPlay=true&autoRewind=false" />
    <embed src="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" flashvars="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Halo_Skin_3&streamName=LeadershipRocklandFinal&autoPlay=true&autoRewind=false" quality="high" scale="noscale" width="342" height="291" name="FLVPlayer" salign="LT" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The file that flash is requesting is not on the server anymore:

http://www.leadershiprockland.org/LeadershipRocklandFinal.flv

If that is not the correct file path then make sure Flash is requesting the right file.

You can see the 404 in FireBug or Chrome Dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the flash at the top, I see it just fine. Maybe you could take a screenshot in Dreamweaver and show what you're talking about? Also, try resetting your settings in your browser/changing browsers (not just changing computers).

Comment: What would this have to do with local browser settings? This page worked fine until yesterday, and I had not touched anything on the site at all. No uploads or deletions. If it displayed fine and now does not work across multiple platforms or computers then it has to be beyond my individual browser, doesn't it?

Comment: I think you're right. just trying the available options ;) but it looks like @citizen conn had a good answer. did that not solve it?

Comment: No, I have checked and the flv file and the swf created when I embedded the file both show as being uploaded to the site. I have no clue why this would all of a sudden stop working and no matter how I try to re-upload the page or the files it no longer works.

Comment: Despite something saying the file was uploaded....it just isn't there. The file you're linking to, the one @citizen conn provided, doesn't exist, which is why it's not showing up on the page. I would advise trying to upload it again or saving the file as a .mov or something else.

Comment: Hate to disagree, but the file is there. It has to be something with the way dreamweaver is embedding it (I've updated the OP with the embed code) or perhaps an issue with my ISP? BTW I'm still using Dreamweaver 8, which should not make a difference but I've included that bit of info as well.

Comment: how is the file there if the link is giving a 404?

Comment: I have read elsewhere that the issue could be server-related. I will assume that is the case since I uploaded the exact same video in the exact same manner on another site I run that is hosted on a different server and it plays just fine, as it did up until a few days ago on the server I now have problems with. I am waiting for a response from the host's support.

Comment: Today the video mysteriously appeared again on the site - but the skin with the video controls does not appear - just can't figure it out - hopefully get to speak to someone in support tomorrow.